# How do i use default android resources in my layout xml?

Tags: android, xml, layout, resources, default

There are loads of default resources in android. I want to use the `android.R.string.cancel` and `android.R.string.ok`.

I can do this in code easily enough

```
getString(android.R.string.cancel)
```

but how do do it in the layout.xml

```
@string/cancel
```

Tried a few things

```
@android.R.string/cancel
@android.string/cancel
```

but these do not work. I'm sure I have seen this on dev tutorials, but can't find it all now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's actually @android:string/cancel

Comment: Thanks, just having a memory blank and couldn't find an example any where!

Comment: Your question took me by surprise, and got me a memory blank as well :-) But I found the answer here : http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/07/using-the-standard-android-icons-in-your-own-application/